# Check if a file is a symlink in Rust 2018 on Windows

Tags: windows, rust, symlink, rust-2018

I'm writing a small utility for myself that needs to be able to check if a file is a symlink or not.

Using [`FileType::is_symlink`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.FileType.html#method.is_symlink) on Windows always returns `false` (goes for both symlinks to directories, and regular files).

Using regular Rust 2018 edition, is there any way to check if a file is a symlink on Windows?

In my searching, I came across: [`FileTypeExt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/windows/fs/trait.FileTypeExt.html) - however this requires that you use unstable Rust, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Just checking, did you follow the doc instructions and use `fs::symlink_metadata` to get the file type?

Comment: Can confirm `fs::symlink_metadata(path)?.file_type().is_symlink()` works on Windows. Whereas using `fs::metadata()` "wouldn't" as it follows the links.

Comment: Also note that saying that you're using Rust 2018 is usually not as useful as giving us the Rust version you're using. The standard library changes a lot across versions.

Comment: Thanks to you all.  Yes fs::symlink_metadata(path)?.file_type().is_symlink() does actually work.  I must have misunderstood that part of the docs.  Happy to mark as answer if someone wants to post it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`File::metadata()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.File.html#method.metadata) or [`fs::metadata()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.metadata.html) to get the file type will always return false for [`FileType::is_symlink()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.FileType.html#method.is_symlink) because the link has already been followed at that point. The [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.FileType.html#method.is_symlink) note that:

> The underlying [`Metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.Metadata.html) struct needs to be retrieved with the [`fs::symlink_metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.symlink_metadata.html) function and not the [`fs::metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.metadata.html) function. The [`fs::metadata`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.metadata.html) function follows symbolic links, so [`is_symlink`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.FileType.html#method.is_symlink) would always return `false` for the target file.

```
use std::fs;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let metadata = fs::symlink_metadata("foo.txt")?;
    let file_type = metadata.file_type();

    let _ = file_type.is_symlink();
    Ok(())
}
```